# How to create cross sections from vector point layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cross-section

I have a set of points (X,Y,Z) across a river. Is there a way to present them as a cross section?
I'm attaching a cross section I made in Excel: The X axis are the longtitude and the Y axis, the Z elevation data.
I want to make such a cross section in QGIS. [image]

Comment: Can you add a drawing to illustrate what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need a general plotting library for this - so you could either use R or Python, and then write a script for the Processing module to get the data from your layer and plot.

Answer (score 1):

In a first step, you should convert your point layer into a DEM raster: [Creating raster or vector raster from DEM point file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28237/creating-raster-or-vector-raster-from-dem-point-file) or [How to rasterize a vector map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55458/how-to-rasterize-a-vector-map)

Then you can follow this advice: [Drawing cross section in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/how-to-draw-a-cross-section-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks Andre, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.
The data points I have are too few and too scattered for creating a reasonable raster.

Comment: If they are not part of the cross-section cutline, QGIS has to interpolate between them. And the rasterize tool does exactly the same.