# Rasterizing z values from vector grid points as centroid of cells?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have read some Q&As related to this:

- [Creating raster or vector raster from DEM point file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28237/creating-raster-or-vector-raster-from-dem-point-file]),

  - [Does a value in srtm dem file refer to the center or corner of a cell?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30415/does-a-value-in-srtm-dem-file-refer-to-the-center-or-corner-of-a-cell?rq=1)

However, none specifically answer my question.

I have a number of 5x5 m grids consisting of X,Y,Z coordinates (DEM) each representing one tile, once rasterized and each 5x5 km in size (a lot of data!).
If I use gdal_rasterize in QGIS, the calculated raster contains cells between four grid points, resulting in no data gaps between the tiles. What I want is a raster that assigns the z value of the grid points as centroids of the cells. That way, I expect the no data line to disappear between the tiles.
As I will have to convert approx. 90 grid files to raster tiles, a batch process would be the best solution.

Which process to rasterize a grid can I use in QGIS to assign z values as centroids of the raster cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAGA-GIS tool (in the processing toolbox) Rasterize will do this for you. There is an option near the bottom of the UI labelled 'fit'. If you use input points and select 'cells' it will create the raster with each input point at the centre of the relevant raster cell.

The SAGA tools can easily be used from the command line, or you can use them in batch mode from the processing toolbox, so you can automate them easily enough.

[image: Rasterize UI]